# Swap Elastic Beanstalk URLs with Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I have found this in the AWS documentation, but no explanation or tutorial.

> Deploy application versions with zero downtime in AWS Elastic
>   Beanstalk with a Lambda function that swaps CNAME values.

In this: [Practicing Continuous
Integration and Continuous
Delivery on AWS](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/DevOps/practicing-continuous-integration-continuous-delivery-on-AWS.pdf)

Have you found a way to do it not manually? Or maybe in a config file with the CLI?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any Lambda magic here. That text is simply saying that you could use Lambda to make the CNAME change using the [SwapEnvironmentCNAMEs API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_SwapEnvironmentCNAMEs.html), and that could potentially be a useful option when implementing a [Blue/Green swap with Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html). The AWS CodeStar and CodePipeline services have integration with Lambda, so your CI/CD pipeline can easily call code that will execute in Lambda.

Comment: Thanks Jarmod ! I will try to implement it ! I'm completely new to AWS, not so easy to find every doc etc :)